# Modulo creating bad int for addresses in Hash Table?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable, modulo

HELP! I'm trying to create a hash table using Separate Chaining. For some unknown reason I cant seem to traverse and find all the original int I loaded. I suspect the modulo function is giving me bad addresses sometimes in both functions. First creating bad addresses on assorted int when creating the hash table and then sometimes searching the wrong addresses in the second function while attempting to traverse and confirm my list using modulo again. The hash table is populated by a basic random array of numbers and then I compare the created hash table with the original random array of int. Here is what I believe the culprit is causing all my troubles but I cant be 100% sure:

```
address = randARRAY[key] % MAX_KEYS;
```

And here is the function for creating the Hash Table using Separate Chaining. I generally have MAX_KEYS = 5000, tbSIZE = 8989, which is better than 75% Load factor somewhere around 55%:

```
void separateCHAINING(int *randARRAY,int tbSIZE,TABLE *head[]){
  int key = 0,
    address = 0,
    collisions = 0,
    newONE = 0;
  randARRAY[MAX_KEYS + 1] = 0;
  TABLE *newADDRESS[tbSIZE];
  newADDRESS[tbSIZE] = new TABLE();

  for(int a = 0; a < tbSIZE; a++){
    newADDRESS[a] = NULL;
    head[a] = NULL;
  }

  while(randARRAY[key] != 0){
    address = randARRAY[key] % MAX_KEYS;
    newADDRESS[address] = new TABLE;
    newADDRESS[address]->key = randARRAY[key];
    if(head[address] != 0){
      newADDRESS[address]->next = head[address]->next;
      head[address]->next = newADDRESS[address];
      collisions++;
    }
    else{
      newADDRESS[address]->next = head[address];
      head[address] = newADDRESS[address]; 
      newONE++;   
    }
    key++;  
  }
  cout << "total collisions: " << collisions << endl;
  cout << "new: " << newONE << endl;
  cout << "added: " << collisions + newONE << endl;
  cout << "key: " << key << endl;
}
```

This created data appears to be passed without issue. I used gdb to create a ridiculously long list on one array index and it was all there in the second function without missing any nodes. This is why I think the addresses might be getting botched by modulo in both the function above and on this one below. This is apparently creating bogus addresses and then calling the wrong ones later. In the end Im never able to find all my int for the random array put in the Hash Table. Here is the function which uses modulo again and then tries to traverse and match the random array against the new hash table:

```
void tableTWO_MATCH(int *randARRAY,TABLE *HT_TWO[]){
  int key = 0,
    address = 0,
    match = 0,
    nomatch = 0;
  randARRAY[MAX_KEYS + 1] = 0;

  while(randARRAY[key] != 0){
    address = randARRAY[key] % MAX_KEYS;
    while(HT_TWO[address]->next != NULL && HT_TWO[address]->key != randARRAY[key]){         
      HT_TWO[address] = HT_TWO[address]->next;
    }//end second while 
    if(HT_TWO[address]->key == randARRAY[key]){
      match++;

    }//end if
    if(HT_TWO[address]->key != randARRAY[key]){
      nomatch++;            
    }//end if
    key = key + 1;
    address = 0;

  }//end outer while
  cout << "match: " << match << endl;
  cout << "not match: " << nomatch << endl;
  cout << "key: " << key << endl;
}
```

As always thank you ahead of time for any assistance! I will be grateful if you can see where I'm messing up!

Comment: Can your random function generate negative values? % can gives negative result for negative operands.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using STL containers to help yourself out here?  slist and vector would go a long ways towards my piece of mind in knowing you haven't accidently written off the end of an array or to a bogus next pointer.  This code is C with new and cout.  Make it truly C++ and help yourself out a bit.

Comment: nit: the excessive use of ALL CAPS makes your code somewhat hard to understand.

Comment: OK I will look to see if my rand function is creating negative numbers at some point in the array. I don't believe it is but you may be on to something as I had other issues with the loop earlier in my other functions with it passing the end of the random array and creating negative numbers.

Comment: Michael, For the purpose of this project I will not be using vectors. Trust me if I could I would. This is for learning data structures which is why its C with C++. I cant wait to use the real power of C++.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess I'm just a bone head! I used a boolean variable to check and see if a match was found at any point in time during traversal.

```
if(HT_TWO[address]->key == randARRAY[key]){
          found = true;
        }
```

I was trying to match nodes that had traversed past their match and getting poor results. Anyway This is how I changed my verification using boolen instead. Thanks for your help guys!

```
void tableTWO_MATCH(int *randARRAY,TABLE *HT_TWO[]){
  int key = 0,
    address = 0,
    match = 0,
    nomatch = 0;
  bool found = false;
  randARRAY[MAX_KEYS + 1] = 0;

  while(randARRAY[key] != 0){
    address =  HASH(randARRAY[key],MAX_KEYS);
    if(HT_TWO[address]->key == randARRAY[key]){
      match++;
    }
    else{
      while(HT_TWO[address]->next != NULL){         
    HT_TWO[address] = HT_TWO[address]->next;
    if(HT_TWO[address]->key == randARRAY[key]){
      found = true;
    }     
      }//end second while 
      if(found == false){
    nomatch++;
      }

    }
    key = key + 2;      
  }//end outer while
  cout << "not match: " << nomatch << endl;
  cout << "key: " << key << endl;
}
```